# How to get a same result of Views with Random Sort Criteria

Tags: views

There is a View which it's Sort Criteria is Random.I have to use the following code to implement two different displays of **one** view.

```
print views_embed_view("library","block_0",$term->tid);
$views = views_get_view_result("library","block_0",$term->tid);
//some other codes that retrieve data from $views
```

The problem is, because the View is Random the above two lines return different results while I need to have one. How do I can solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need two calls of views because it's in different places?

Comment: @Eugene I called it twice because every one of those functions returns different result. The first one display the view but the second one returns the properties like the `nid` of the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
$views = views_get_view("views_name");
dsm($views->preview('display_id')); // instead of views_embed_view
dsm($views->result); // Instead of views_get_view_result()
```

Comment: I tried this: `$views = views_get_view("library");$views->set_display('block_0');$views->set_arguments(array($term->tid));kpr($views->result);`

but the result of an empty array!

Comment: Did you aded `$view->execute();` before `kpr()`?

Answer (score 1):

if its in the same context, you can assign a variable and print it twice

```
$output = views_embed_view("library","block_0",$term->tid);

print $output;
print $output;
```

if that is not the idea, you could simply do what views_embed_view() does manually by loading the view first which gives you access to the content, and then calling the preview - here's the code from the function:

```
function views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default') {
  $args = func_get_args();
  array_shift($args); // remove $name
  if (count($args)) {
    array_shift($args); // remove $display_id
  }

  $view = views_get_view($name);
  if (!$view || !$view->access($display_id)) {
    return;
  }

  return $view->preview($display_id, $args);
}
```